# Show password of mounted DMG file

Tags: disk-utility, password, dmg

I recently created 3 encrypted DMG files using the same password for all of them. Apparently I do not correctly remember the password anymore but one of the DMG files is still mounted. Is it possible to read out the password of a DMG file when it is mounted? The info folder of finder and disk utility do not seem to provide the possibility to show the password, but maybe it is stored somewhere within the DMG file and can be read out?

Comment: Did you put the password into the Keychain?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I am still a bit puzzled that I don't seem to remember the pwd correctly because I thought I only deleted one letter from another pwd which I frequently use. I didn't expect I would run into trouble with it.

Comment: Leaving passwords in memory (or storing it in the DMG) would be bad security practice (for hopefully obvious reasons).